# column not found while renaming in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this panda dataframe

```
timestamp    EG2021   EGH2021
2021-01-04    33        Nan
2021-02-04    45        65
```

And I Am trying to replace the columnm name with new name as mapped in an excel file like this

```
     OldId           NewId
     EG2021        LER_EG2021
     EGH2021       LER_EGH2021
```

I tried below code but its not working I get the error as

> KeyError: "None of [Index(['LER_EG2021',LER_EGH2021'],\n
> dtype='object', length=186)] are in the [columns]

Code:

```
df = pd.ExcelFile('ids.xlsx').parse('Sheet1')
x=[]
x.append(df['external_ids'].to_list())
dtest_df = (my panda dataframe as mentioned above)
mapper = df.set_index(df['oldId'])[df['NewId']]
dtest_df.columns = dtest_df.columns.Series.replace(mapper)
```

Any idea what wrong am I doing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
mapper = df.set_index('oldId')['NewId']
dtest_df.columns = dtest_df.columns.map(mapper.to_dict())
```

Or:

```
dtest_df = dtest_df.rename(columns=df.set_index('oldId')['NewId'].to_dict())
```

`dtest_df` output:

```
    timestamp    LER_EG2021   LER_EGH2021
0  2021-01-04            33           NaN
1  2021-02-04            45            65
```

Comment: I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Another way, dict the zip of the df with the Old and New ids

```
dtest_df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df['OldId'], df['NewId'])), inplace=True)



 timestamp       LER_EG2021   LER_EGH2021
0  2021-01-04          33         Nan
1  2021-02-04          45          65
```